# "using '!' logical when bitwise '~' was probably intended"

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am trying to adapt some code I found online for calculating a parabolic SAR (https://github.com/TulipCharts/tulipindicators/blob/master/indicators/psar.c). Being C, it runs fine.

But in C++, I get a green ziggy line under `!lng` saying:

> using '!' logical when bitwise '~' was probably intended

If I change from `lng = !lng;` to `lng = ~lng;`, it computes the incorrect output. So I have left it as the original code.

But I was wondering, how can I fix this/update it to C++, so I don't have the "error" message? Also, what is the difference in C++ between `!` and `~`? Why does it cause a difference in the outputs?

```
if ((lng && low[i] < sar) || (!lng && high[i] > sar)) {
    accel = accel_step;
    sar = extreme;
    lng = !lng;
    if (!lng) extreme = low[i];
    else extreme = high[i];
}
```

Comment: This is something you should be able to configure in your IDE settings

Comment: Use a `bool` instead of an `int`

Comment: Since your question is about the behavior of "a green ziggy", it may help you to explain _what the green ziggy is_.  An IDE feature, I presume.  Which IDE?  Is it using any cutom _green ziggy_ plugins?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to clear up confusion:

If you change the line `lng = !lng` to be `lng = ~lng`, here's what happens. If the value of `lng` is 0, the bitwise complement will give you `0xffffffff`, assuming a 32-bit integer. If this value is used in a boolean check, it will evaluate to "true" because it's non-zero. If the value of `lng` is 1, the bitwise complement will give you `0xfffffffe`, which will also evaluate to "true" in a boolean check, again because it's nonzero. This is why it breaks your code.

If you want to compile with a C++ compiler, you can change the type of `lng` to `bool` as others have suggested. If you're planning to stick with C, you can also use `bool`, but you'll need to first `#include <stdbool.h>`, and make sure you're compiling with a C version greater than or equal to C99.

Another way to fix this is just to use an xor with 1 whenever you want to invert the value. So instead of `lng = !lng` (which the compiler expands logically to `lng = (lng != 0)` as @BenVoigt pointed out), you can do `lng ^= 1`. This allows you to continue treating `lng` as an integer numeric value (i.e. not a bool in the strictest sense) and thereby get rid of the warning without changing much else.

Comment: The actual translation of `lng = !lng` for integer variables is `lng = (lng != 0)` and not `lng ^= 1`

Comment: Indeed, helpful addition @BenVoigt, thank you. I didn't mean to imply these are the same operation, just a different approach to eliminating the warning while keeping the original `int` type. I'll make a note of this in my answer.

Comment: Only a broken compiler would translate `lng = !lng` to `lng = (lng != 0)`. If anything, it should be **`lng = (lng == 0)`** ... While I'm at it, you *could* also abuse the "!" operator to get rid of the warning: `lng = !!!lng`

Answer (score 0):

Since we now know that the green ziggy in question is displayed in VS 2022, it's possible to formulate an answer.

I think this warning is just noise personally - that code is perfectly legitimate as it was - but fortunately there's a way to turn it off.  Just change:

`Options -> Text Editor -> C/C++ -> Code Style -> Linter -> Logical/Bitwise Mismatch`

to None and you're done.